# How to webflux customer router write:get post

Tags: spring-webflux

I want to implement router rule:

---

- 1、the url request is get:/api?method=login&...
- 2、the url request is post: /api  ,the body contains method param
- 3、the url prefix is not /api or method param is not exist，then throw exception:404

How I do?

```
@Bean   
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
   return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r.path("/api").and().query("method").and().query("method", "login").uri("lb://bizservice-sys")

            )
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Spring Boot, here's a code snippet:

```
@Bean // add that bean method in a configuration class
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(MyHandler handler) {

    return RouterFunctions
            .route(GET("/api").and(queryParam("method", "login")), handler::login)
            .andRoute(POST("/api"), handler::method);
}

@Component // create that component as a class
class MyHandler {

    Mono<ServerResponse> login(ServerRequest request) {
        return //...
    }

    Mono<ServerResponse> method(ServerRequest request) {
        return //...
    }

}
```